# How to assign a value into a variable in a shell script from a java code

Tags: java, bash, shell, parameters

I have a variable parameter ( retrieved from a getText field in Seleium Automation) that i want to assign the value into a specefic place in a shell script :

In java this is what i do :

```
String ref = workcreation.getfield_ref().getText(); 


  try {  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/script.sh");
            Process p = pb.start();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);

                System.out.println("in " + reader);

            }
            p.waitFor();

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

In script script.sh, i want to assign the value of ref into the parameter &ref in that exact place  :

```
##it is the value of &ref that i want to get 
if [  -d "/data/techVersion_$ref" ]; then
echo "le dossier  existe dans cccc "

else
echo " le dossier  n'existe pas dans  cccc !"
exit
fi
```

what can i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass arguments to your command/script by ProcessBuilder.

In your shell script, you can read the argument. A simple example is:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/script.sh", "hello");
```

in your script:

```
echo "variable set in java: $1"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ProcessBuilder` takes an arbitrary number of `String`s as arguments. The first one has to be the executable itself, in your case it is the script `"/home/script.sh"`. You are currently just passing the executable as a single argument. Just add the parameters for your script to the constructor call of `ProcessBuilder`.

Your line

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/script.sh");
```

should be replaced by this

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/script.sh", "firstArg", "secondArg");
```

or you create a `List<String>` containing the executable as first element followed by the parameters, like

```
List<String> execPlusArgs = new ArrayList<String>();
execPlusArgs.add("/home/script.sh");
execPlusArgs.add("firstArg");
execPlusArgs.add("secondArg");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(execPlusArgs);
```